# Как использовать MVVM в реальном приложении

Tags: c#, mvvm

Очень много теории про MVVM, а практические примеры разнятся так что только в путь. По этому назрел вопрос о том, как всеже "правильно" делать.

Вопрос А :
Предположим:

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
string A;
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
string B {get Model.A + "some chars"};
}
```

И в итоге ничего апдейтится не будет(и понятно почему). Как правильно поступать в таких ситуациях?

Вопрос Б:

```
class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 string SomeString;
}

class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 array SomeList<Item>[];
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 Model model;
}
```

Как привязыватся к model.A.[элемент], так, чтобы не терять апдейты?

Спасибо

Comment: Ну для начала вам стоит реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и в сеттере вызывать инвокатор этого события, с передачей имени **свойства**, но **не поля**.

Comment: Это подразумевается в примере

Comment: В вопросе A, как я понимаю, есть только вариант отлавливать все события, фильтровать и тогда обновлять свойство верхнего уровня. Но это столько никчемных событий, а в случае высоконагруженного сервиса - лишнее время. Есть альтернативы?

Comment: **A:** Я правильно понимаю, что вы просто хотите добавить к определенному свойству некий текст? Если да, то это я думаю стоит сделать на View уровне, путем добавления `StringFormat` у привязки. **Б:** Классы в C# - это ссылочные типы, а значит вам достаточно получить ссылку на `model.A.[элемент]` и реализовать свойство в VM слое, которое будет предоставлять эту ссылку (прим: `public MyProp => model.A.[элемент];)`. Если `[элемент]` будет реализовать `INPC`, то все привязки будут работать как надо и все данные обновятся.

Comment: Также хочу заметить тот факт, что `INPC` нужно реализовать только у тех классов, свойства которых могут измениться во время работы приложения. Допустим если брать ваш "Б" вопрос, то там `INPC` нужен по сути только у `Item` (если он конечно подразумевает изменение своих данных). Другие же классы просто хранят "статичные" значения, которые вы не будете изменять во время работы. Может конечно `array SomeList<Item>[];`, если тут будет постоянное `= new...`, то да, тут тоже нужен `INPC`, ибо данные свойства будут изменятся.